# jQuery Datatables slow initialization in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, datatables

I have been working with DataTables for the last months and have already implemented server side processing with success. However the last requirement I was given was to have a search input in order to filter across all columns (like the predefault search for client side processing(CSP)).

As I antecipated that implementing that filter in server side processing (SSP) would result in a really slow query I switched my focus to CSP. Everything is working fine...except the usual suspect IE8 (requirement). The sort, paging and filtering all work really well in IE, however the initial loading is really slow and filled with "A script on this page is causing Internet Explorer to run slowly" dialogs. I spent the day reading the Datatables forum and SO looking for solutions, and did some experiments but nothing works (if I return more than ~2000 I get the damned dialog - I am testing with ~4000 rows):

-Using rows.add() in chunks of the returned JSON object (adapted the solution provided here [DataTables Forum IE fix](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/16655/ie8-a-script-on-this-page-is-causing-your-web-browser-to-run-slowly) to work for version 1.10.3)

-Using deferRender = true

Notes:

1- I have some columns(4-5) that must use the render function in order to display custom data

2- I have some hidden columns (read somewhere that IE had some problems with hidden columns/table placeholder).

If someone has some more options I could try, I would be grateful!
Thank you in advance

**EDIT**: Couple of things I have already tried:

-Removed all the render functions;

-Made all columns not sortable;

-I have a bunch of click handlers that I was assigning in the DataTable's drawCallBack option: I switched it to delegate handlers and assigned them before initializing the table.

I still have the slow dialog...I am running my application in a VM with IE8, does the hardware have any impact? Given that the dialog is caused by the number of Javascript statements ran I doubt it, but I am not certain.

Comment: it depends on how you are building the grid and how many custom API callbacks you use, but some old tricks might help: 1. making the element hidden until it's ready tends to help in old IE. 2. defer the ajax loading slightly so that your CPU time spent on the page load isn't counted towards the timeout of the load produced by building the table; that won't make it faster, but it can prevent the dialog. 3. hide the table while you call rows.add.

Comment: 1- What element are you refering? The table hidden cells or the placeholder for the table? 2- Already tried making the ajax call before and suplying the returned JSON to the plugin and it's not that different. 3- I will try it now, but why should it matter?